# What lightweight solution can you recommend to stream MP3 files?

Tags: linux, streaming, mp3

I need to stream MP3 files to a client running Flash. Streaming is the key here, no progressive downloads allowed.

What free server can you recommend? I know Red5 but it seems a bit overkill for our needs (basic MP3 streaming). Anything more lightweight?

Our Webserver runs Linux and Apache and we can install stuff there as long as it doesn't bog down the machine. Plus there is Perl and PHP although I don't think this will help for streaming, right?

Thank you!

Comment: How many concurrent users? Flash Media Server trial license gives you 5 concurrent, but it's just as heavy as Red5

Comment: Probably no more than 20 or so.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at [icecast2](http://www.icecast.org/). It's capable of serving MP3 streams (as well as other media like Theora and Vorbis) at high performance level.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [gnump3d](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnump3d).